# Can't click on button Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm having trouble clicking on the "next" button on this page:

https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/district/alsd/2021/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22500%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D

I've tried by xpath, css_selector and no dice.  Here's the code:

```
try:
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="collapseOne3578"]/div/span[1]/div/ul/li[4]')
        if next_page:   
                print('Trying to get next page')
                print(next_page)
                next_page.click()
        else:
            continue
except:
    break
```

I put the variable in a try statement because some pages do not have results over 500 and therefore no next button.  If I defined the variable outside of the statement the code breaks.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong locator.
Please try this:

```
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="next fw-pagination-btn"]')
```

or this

```
next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.next.fw-pagination-btn')
```

Don't forget to add a wait, preferably expecting condition, before locating the element.

Comment: Hi :) you have a typo in the css example, `css-selector` should have underscore instead of hyphen.  Also I like the selector `li.next.fw-pagination-btn` better but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I've tried both ways and I get: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //li[@class="next fw-pagination-btn"]

Comment: Did you try adding sleep / wait?

Comment: This worked.  next_page = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//li[@class="next fw-pagination-btn"]'))). But I have a new problem: how to load the new results in selenium so that I can continue to grab the new data?  Does click() refresh the data?

Comment: As you mentioned, this is a a new question. Stackoverflow rules demand to ask only one question per question. So, please accept this answer and then please ask a new separate question. We will be happy to assist you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a[text()='Next']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The element was not visible so I used:

```
next_page = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//li[@class="next fw-pagination-btn"]')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', next_page)
```

And it worked.